# Remove folder including content from a pull request in Git

Tags: git, github, version-control, versioning, pull-request

I made a pull request and now I have to remove the .vscode folder before merging.

How can I remove the folder from my branch and then push the version without this folder again?

The .vscode folder is in my .gitignore, but is constantly ignored. I have to remove this manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Assuming you're the "owner" of your feature branch, like in many workflows.)*

```
# start from your feature branch
git checkout <feature-branch>

# undo last commit but keep changes in the working tree (and index)
git reset --soft HEAD^

# get your unwanted folder out of the index
git reset HEAD -- path/to/folder

# redo your commit, this time without the folder
git commit -m "Useful message"

# push to the remote to replace the old ref, thus needing --force
git push -f origin HEAD
```

At this point, the remote will just need a page refresh (to update your pull request with the new branch ref) and you'll be set to merge your branch, this time without the "bad" folder.

Comment: @Codehan25 Yes, that's the reason for the 'forced' push. I *assumed* you indeed already pushed.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually remove the folder, and `git commit --amend` to your existing commit, and `git push -f orign YOUR_BRANCH`

FYI, make sure `.vscode/` is in your .gitignore, ending / is needed.

Comment: The Docs say "If the commit only exists in your local repository and has not been pushed to GitHub, you can amend the commit message with the git commit --amend command. On the command line, navigate to the repository that contains the commit you want to amend. In your text editor, edit the commit message and save the commit." - So my commit is also on the remote repo. The .vscode is in my .gitignore like .vscode/ and /.vscode/ but it gets irgnored :(

Comment: Since your commit is also on the remote repo, that's why we need **git push -f origin YOUR_BRANCH** to force push, so that it will overwrite the previous one. Regarding the ignore file, maybe give a try for https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/VisualStudioCode.gitignore